# Storage Spaces Pool - MediaType incompatible with type

Tags: windows-server-2019, storage-spaces

Failing to create a virtual disk in Server 2019 due to 2 of the 6 drives having unknown MediaType. Tried setting media type whilst they are in and out of the pool but always same error:

> Set-PhysicalDisk -UniqueId "50014EE0AD6D766F" -MediaType HDD
>
> Set-PhysicalDisk : The value supplied is incompatible with the type.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Set-PhysicalDisk –UniqueId "50014EE0AD6D766F" -MediaType HDD
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (PS_StorageCmdlets:ROOT/Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Set->PhysicalDisk], C
>   imException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 13,Set-PhysicalDisk
>   ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't I feel like an idiot. I assumed as I was admin, commands would run with admin rights. Wrong. Opened powershell as admin, low and behold command worked first time.